# Может ли SOCKs proxy скрывать информацию об ОС, получаемую через TCP

Tags: proxy

Возможно ли получить информацию о tcp headers клиента, если он подключается через SOCKs proxy, или прокси меняет хедеры на свои?

Answer (score 0):

При желание можно поменять в `headers` на какие угодно данные:
отправляем запрос через утилиту `torsocks` по ходу выставляя какие угодно заголовки:

```
 torsocks curl "http://server.com/" 
                   -H "Pragma: no-cache" 
                   -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" 
                   -H "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" 
                   -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" 
                   -H "User-Agent: SUPER USER BROWSER 2.0" 
                   -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" 
                   -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 
                   -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed
```

И естественно сервер прочитает именно эти заголовки.

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду tcp headers, такие, как: Initial packet size, don't fragment flag и прочие. Если сервер будет анализировать с помощью специальных утилит(таких, как p0f), то сможет с некоторой точностью определить ОС. Но я думаю, что прокси меняет tcp headers на свои, и, таким образом, сервер может узнать ОС только того прокси, который соединился с ним непосредственно. Или все же я ошибаюсь, и сервер получит от прокси те же tcp headers, что и получил бы от моего компа?

Comment: Да это интересный вопрос, ну тут надо дебажить.

Comment: что бы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно рассматривать конкретный прокси. Но, по своему опыту, скорее всего tcp headers  будут независимые.